# Infinite scroll doesnt work

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, infinite-scroll

Im making my own custom type post page, and I wanted to add a *Infinite scroll* with http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ Im added all from examples, and that doesn't work and on developer console, I didnt see the errors or warnings. 
When I click on more, it's redirect me to next page

There's the page full code

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Portfolio page */
get_header();
?>
<script src="http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/js/infinite.min.js"></script>
<script>
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
})
</script>
<body>
<div class="container page">
    <div class="row works infinite-container">
        <?php
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
            elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
            else { $paged = 1; }
            $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=9&post_type=portfolio' . '&paged='.$paged);
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 work">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="work-link"></a>
                <div class="work-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <div class="category-name"><?php the_category('', '', $post->ID); ?></div>
                        <div class="work-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work-thumb">
                    <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>')"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 

        endwhile; 
            if(have_posts() == NULL){
                echo info("Sorry, but there is no content available at this time!");
            }
        ?>
        <a class="infinite-more-link" href="/musu-darbi/page/<?php echo $paged + 1; ?>">More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer()?>
```

Comment: First of all [enqueue your scripts properly](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), meeting their dependencies.

Comment: This tutorial will help you https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

Comment: Do not add the script like you have did ... First do learn how wordpress is working. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: @GrayCarry still the same, put his code, but still the same, doesn't load and no errors :/

Comment: Just apply that tutorial as it is... You will get the result.